# GT.M - Error while building source

Tags: mumps

I get GT.M source from :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fis-gtm/files/GT.M-x86-Linux-src/V6.2-002A/

Extract and do the steps in the README file ,but I get error on the following step :

```
   $ make
```

After that command , error occurred :

```
root@localhost:~/test_gtm/fis-gtm-V6.2-002A/fis-gtm-V6.2-002A# make
[  0%] Built target gen_gtm_threadgbl_deftypes
[  1%] Built target libstub
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/libmumps.dir/sr_unix/ctrly_set.c.o
In file included from /root/test_gtm/fis-gtm-V6.2-002A/fis-gtm-V6.2-002A/sr_unix/ctrly_set.c:17:0:
/root/test_gtm/fis-gtm-V6.2-002A/fis-gtm-V6.2-002A/sr_port/fix_xfer_entry.h:22:23: fatal error: xfer_desc.i: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libmumps.dir/sr_unix/ctrly_set.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libmumps.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I see that bug fix on this :
https://lists.debian.org/debian-med/2012/06/msg00230.html

but it still occurred with me 
Please show me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this problem before.

Try doing xfer_desc.i as the make target itself.

```
sam@thebes:~/repos/fis-gtm-V6.2-002A$ make gen_xfer_desc
Generating xfer_desc.i
Built target gen_xfer_desc
```

Then make the rest.

Comment: Thank ,which folder should I run this command ?.I run from fis-gtm-V6.2-002A in extracted tar file but It said that `make: *** No rule to make target `xfer_desc.i'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 1):

I know we had an error with the CMakeLists.txt files in the original source tarball. I have successfully downloaded and built GT.M from the current source tarball. What is the cksum or md5sum of the source tarball you are using?

Comment: Thanks Mr.Bhaskar , after your comment , I downloaded again source tarball and it working as it should be .Tarball I get error in the question is get from 9/9/2015 , latest is 16/9/2015